# When computing a rotation using quaternion in Unity, it use q * transform.rotation, why not q * transform.rotation * q ^ (-1)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

The `q` in title is a `Quaternion` representing a rotation. But I find some explanation about quaternion used in rotation in Wikipedia and it says: `p' = q*p*q^(-1)`. Why is it that in Unity we don't need to right multiply `q^(-1)`? What does the quaternion mean?

The Wikipedia link is : [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)

Comment: Welcome to quaternions. Good heckin' luck. You're probably better off asking for an explanation over at Mathematics SE and/or just accepting that your code works. Don't anticipate actually *understanding* if you ask over on Math SE though: if you didn't understand the Wikipedia article, I doubt they can help you (and no, I don't understand it either).

Answer (score 2):

Because the product (*) operator is overloaded for the Quaternion class. The implementors choose to simplify (and optimize) the two-side product and provide a one-side product API.

Here is a C++ illustrative pseudo-code:

```
Vector3d Quaternion::operator * (Quaternion q, Vector3d v) 
{
    return ... // compute here q * v * q^-1
}
```